# What is the effect of setting the timeout value to 0 in /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: centos, dns

In order to fix a problem with DNS resolution in a particular customer environment, their admin has suggested adding `options timeout:0` to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file on their CentOS 5 server.

The man page on the OS for `resolv.conf` has this to say about the timeout setting:

> timeout:n
>
> sets the amount of time the resolver will wait for a response from a remote name server before retrying the query via a different name server.  Measured in seconds, the default is RES_TIMEOUT (currently 5, see <resolv.h>).

And I see from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) that there is a silent cap of 30 seconds, but I haven't found any documentation anywhere that tells me what the effect of setting this value to 0 will be.  Does anybody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a good idea when you have more than one nameserver set in your `resolv.conf`. The effect is that the resolver asks the number of nameservers without waiting and returns the first response. It should be used only when your first server in the `resolv.conf` is overloaded. But normally it has no effect, because the dns responses are quick.

Another good solution is to use `nscd - Name service Cache Daemon`.